# Can I decorate an explicit function call such as np.sqrt()

Tags: python, numpy, decorator, python-decorators

I understand a bit about python function decorators. I think the answer to my question is no, but I want to make sure. With a decorator and a numpy array of `x = np.array([1,2,3])` I can override `x.sqrt()` and change the behavior. Is there some way I can override `np.sqrt(x)` in Python?

Use case: working on the [quantities package](http://pythonhosted.org/quantities/user/tutorial.html). Would like to be able to take square root of uncertain quantities without changing code base that currently uses `np.sqrt()`.

**Edit**:

I'd like to modify `np.sqrt` in the `quantities` package so that the following code works (all three should print identical results, note the 0 uncertainty when using `np.sqrt()`). I hope to not require end-users to modify their code, but in the `quantities` package properly wrap/decorate `np.sqrt()`. Currently many numpy functions are decorated (see https://github.com/python-quantities/python-quantities/blob/ca87253a5529c0a6bee37a9f7d576f1b693c0ddd/quantities/quantity.py), but seem to only work when `x.func()` is called, not `numpy.func(x)`.

```
import numpy as np
import quantities as pq
x = pq.UncertainQuantity(2, pq.m, 2)
print x.sqrt()
>>> 1.41421356237 m**0.5 +/- 0.707106781187 m**0.5 (1 sigma)
print x**0.5
>>> 1.41421356237 m**0.5 +/- 0.707106781187 m**0.5 (1 sigma)
print np.sqrt(x)
>>> 1.41421356237 m**0.5 +/- 0.0 dimensionless (1 sigma)
```

Comment: Decorators apply to function *definitions* not function calls.  If the function is already defined, it's too late to use a decorator (although you could achieve the same effect by assigning a wrapped function to the original name).  Can you show an actual code example of what you want to do and what you want the effect to be?

Comment: Example provided. I want to wrap np.sqrt() (and np.mean, etc.) so that it works with the quantities package. Most functions do, but some do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Monkeypatching

If I understand your situation correctly, your use case is not really about decoration (modifying a function *you* write, in a standard manner) 
but rather about *monkey patching:*
Modifying a function somebody else wrote without actually changing that function's definition's source code.

The idiom for what you then need is something like

```
import numpy as np  # provide local access to the numpy module object

original_np_sqrt = np.sqrt

def my_improved_np_sqrt(x):
  # do whatever you please, including:
  # - contemplating the UncertainQuantity-ness of x and
  # - calling original_np_sqrt as needed

np.sqrt = my_improved_np_sqrt
```

Of course, this can change only the future meaning of `numpy.sqrt`,
not the past one.
So if anybody has imported `numpy` before the above and has already used `numpy.sqrt` in a way you would have liked to influence, you lose. 
(And the name to which they map `numpy` does not matter.)

But *after* the above code was executed, the meaning of `numpy.sqrt` in all
modules (whether they imported `numpy` before it or after it)
will be that of `my_improved_np_sqrt`, whether the creators of those modules
like it or not (and of course unless some more monkeypatching of `numpy.sqrt`
is going on elsewhere).

Note that

1. When you do weird things, Python can become a weird platform!
2. When you do weird things, Python can become a weird platform!
3. When you do weird things, Python can become a weird platform!

This is why monkey patching is not normally considered good design style.
So if you take that route, make sure you announce it very prominently
in all relevant documentation.

Oh, and if you do not want to modify other code than that which is 
directly or indirectly executed from your own methods, you could
introduce a decorator that performs monkeypatching before the call
and un-monkeypatching (reassigning `original_np_sqrt`) 
after the call and apply that decorator to
all your functions in question.
Make sure you handle exceptions in that decorator then, so that
the un-monkeypatching is really executed in all cases.

Comment: Hi @Lutz and thank you. Yes I want(ed) to modify a function someone else wrote. I notice your **note** and will not do this. I will just get used to writing code as `x.mean()` instead of my previous way `np.mean(x)`. Just out of curiosity, couldn't a `reload(numpy)` deal with the case of numpy being loaded before my code?

Comment: Well, Python has many things built-in, but *"general undoing and redoing erverything that was done by some module"* is not among them. ``reload`` can change the future, but not the past. In your case, ``reload`` would only undo your assignment to ``numpy.sqrt``, not magically modify anything else.

Comment: How to do this globally for numpy rather than on a case-by-case basis (and in 2022!)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, as BrenBarn stated,

```
np.sqrt = decorator(np.sqrt)
```

because a decorator is just a callable that takes an object and returns a modified object.

Comment: I think I'm over my head with decorators. The package includes code I'm not yet able to grok for decorating: https://github.com/python-quantities/python-quantities/blob/ca87253a5529c0a6bee37a9f7d576f1b693c0ddd/quantities/decorators.py

Comment: I understand your example. But can I have `import pkg` overload np.sqrt not knowing exactly how it will be called (i.e. `from numpy import *; sqrt();` or `import numpy as n; n.sqrt()`. Would this work only if `pkg` imported *after* numpy?

Comment: @mankoff: Actually it would work only if `pkg` were imported *before* numpy.

Comment: Hm. I have simple decorators working on my own functions, but cannot modify the results of `np.sqrt`. Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: @BrenBarn, how would something be able to modify something it hasn't imported yet? i.e. how could pkg change np.sqrt without first importing it? (short of modifying the source code, which i believe is frowned upon)

Comment: @acushner: `pkg` would have to import numpy and modify it.  It would have to be imported before numpy, beause it would need to be the first thing to import numpy, in order to ensure that whatever wrapping it does applies to everything else that imports numpy.