# Detecting unexpected type conversion in python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a piece of complex Python code involving the using of 32-bit numerical values (for saving memory and bandwidth). But later I discovered many of these 32-bit numbers were implicitly converted to 64-bit in some high-level functions. For example, the sum function, by default, can transforms a 32bit array to a 64bit number.

```
In [152]: x32
Out[152]:
array([  0.      ,   1.010101,   2.020202,   3.030303,   4.040404,
         5.050505,   6.060606,   7.070707,   8.080808,   9.090909,
        10.10101 ,  11.111111,  12.121212,  13.131313,  14.141414,
        15.151515,  16.161615,  17.171717,  18.181818,  19.19192 ,
        20.20202 ,  21.212122,  22.222221,  23.232323,  24.242424,
        25.252525,  26.262627,  27.272728,  28.282827,  29.292929,
        30.30303 ,  31.313131,  32.32323 ,  33.333332,  34.343433,
        35.353535,  36.363636,  37.373737,  38.38384 ,  39.39394 ,
        40.40404 ,  41.414143,  42.424244,  43.434345,  44.444443,
        45.454544,  46.464645,  47.474747,  48.484848,  49.49495 ,
        50.50505 ,  51.515152,  52.525253,  53.535355,  54.545456,
        55.555557,  56.565655,  57.575756,  58.585857,  59.59596 ,
        60.60606 ,  61.61616 ,  62.626263,  63.636364,  64.64646 ,
        65.65656 ,  66.666664,  67.676765,  68.68687 ,  69.69697 ,
        70.70707 ,  71.71717 ,  72.72727 ,  73.73737 ,  74.747475,
        75.757576,  76.76768 ,  77.77778 ,  78.78788 ,  79.79798 ,
        80.80808 ,  81.818184,  82.828285,  83.83839 ,  84.84849 ,
        85.85859 ,  86.86869 ,  87.878784,  88.888885,  89.89899 ,
        90.90909 ,  91.91919 ,  92.92929 ,  93.93939 ,  94.94949 ,
        95.959595,  96.969696,  97.9798  ,  98.9899  , 100.      ],
      dtype=float32)

In [153]: sum(x32)
Out[153]: 4999.999972701073

In [154]: type(sum(x32))
Out[154]: numpy.float64
```

The reason in this case sum(x32) is 64-bit should be from the default accumulator of sum, 0, as shown here:

```
In [156]: type(sum(x32, start=np.float32(0)))
Out[156]: numpy.float32
```

Above, I use the sum function as an example, to explain type conversion is everywhere if I use 32bit as inputs. I have changed the `sum` part to avoid such implicit type conversion.
But I would like to know if internally in my library call, there is any other unexpected 32bit -> 64bit conversion. Is there a general programming language solution to monitor any possible type conversion? For example, can I run my python code with some special debugging tool so that any type conversion from 32bit to 64bit will trigger an alarm or being logged?

Comment: You could use np.sum instead, keeping in mind that numpy will not report overflow and will not give the right answer if you exceed int32.

Comment: Thanks. I used the sum function as an example, to explain type conversion is everywhere if I use 32bit as inputs. So the question is how can we monitor these type conversion systematically?

Comment: Why not save your initial dtype, carry out the operation, save that dtype and then assert them to be equal? You could make a decorator to assist too. Not sure of the best way to decorate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600365/can-i-decorate-an-explicit-function-call-such-as-np-sqrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are nearly there to be honest.

```py
original_dtype = x32.dtype

new_dtype = sum(x32, start=np.float32(0))).dtype

assert new_dtype == original_dtype, f"dtypes differ, {new_dtype=} != {original_dtype=}"
```

To use this method globally, you can write something like:

```py
def type_checker_func(func,input_array,*args):

    dtype_orig = input_array.dtype

    result = func(input_array,*args)

    dtype_new = result.dtype

    if dtype_new != dtype_orig:
        print(f"dtypes differ, {dtype_new=} != {dtype_orig=}")

    return result

my_answer = type_checker_func(sum,x32,start=np.float32(0))
```

But I am not sure how you would best handle multiple return values (consider `np.histogram`), all sorts of args, etc. etc.

I am also not sure how to invoke the `type_checker_func` globally / implicitly (if only for numpy fns).

Update: I posted a github question asking about doing this for every function call using line_profiler - see https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/188 - fingers crossed.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is how to invoke the type_checker_func globally and implicitly for all functions. My code consists of high-level tensorflow code. It looks not easy to force the use of type_checker_function everywhere internally.

Comment: @zell I think you could try hacking https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler or https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler [no longer maintained in the case of the latter :( ]. Maybe post some issues on their respective github pages and see if they can assist?

Comment: @zell I opened a line_profiler github issue - see here https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/188